# Как получить данные из БД Room с помощью RxJava если с удаленного сервера пришла ошибка

Tags: android, rxjava, android-room

Всем привет. Пишу приложение в котором запрашивается погода с удаленного сервера. Для Api запроса использую библиотеку Retrofit   и RxJava. Сейчас мне нужно добавить в приложение БД Room, если при Api запросе получаю ошибку то нужно взять данные из БД и отобразить их пользователю, а если Api запрос прошел успешно то нужно сохранить данные в БД. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать с помошью RxJava?

Интерфейс Dao

```
@Dao
interface WeatherDataDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertWeatherData(weatherDataEntity: WeatherDataEntity): Single<WeatherDataEntity>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM weather_data WHERE city_name = :cityName AND date = :date ")
    fun getWeatherDataFromDb(cityName: String, date: String): Single<WeatherDataEntity>
}
```

Так выглядит код репозитория сейчас, мне нужно изменить его добавив туда БД

```
package com.example.data.implementationRepo

import com.example.data.apiservice.WeatherDataApiService
import com.example.data.mappers.WeatherDataMapper
import com.example.domain.models.WeatherData
import com.example.domain.repositories.WeatherDataRepository
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single

class WeatherDataRepositoryImpl(
    private val weatherDataApiService: WeatherDataApiService,
    private val mapper: WeatherDataMapper,
    private val weatherDataDao: WeatherDataDao
) : WeatherDataRepository {

    override fun getWeatherData(city: String, days: Int, degreeType: String): Single<WeatherData> =
        weatherDataApiService.getWeatherData(city, days, degreeType)
            .map { mapper.mapWeather(it) }

}
```

Comment: onErrorResumeNext ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод `onErrorReturn()`

```
weatherDataApiService.getWeatherData(city, days, degreeType)
        .map { mapper.mapWeather(it) }
        .onErrorResumeNext { getDataFromCache() }
```

Если у вас уже есть готовое значение(например дефолтное какое-то) вы можете использовать `onErrorReturn()`:

```
weatherDataApiService.getWeatherData(city, days, degreeType)
        .map { mapper.mapWeather(it) }
        .onErrorReturn { getDataFromCache() }
```

Comment: При успешном Api запросе, где сохранять данные в БД? Как я понимаю в методе map{} нельзя будет?

Comment: Можно  flatMap и вернуть single.just(it). Можно в success. Можно в doOnSuccess{}. Я так не скажу сходу что лучше, надо более подробного почитать документацию этих методов. В целом вы можете создать отдельный Observable вроде такого saveTodatabase ().anThen{Single.just(it)} где it это то что придет в цепочке в ваш flatMap, и просто потом его же дальше вернуть по цепочке. И этот Observable вызвать во flatMap

Comment: Не уверен что нормально смог объяснить

Comment: А вообще если вам не важен результат то вы можете и в map это сделать если ваш map не на UI потоке